# Filter tasks in Windows Task Scheduler by action

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I am trying to find a task in Windows Task Scheduler on an image of a Windows 10 x64.

All I know about this taks is that when it is triggered, it disables a service which I also know nothing about.

I have manually gone through Task Scheduler a few times but have not been able to find it.

Event Viewer and auditing was disabled before I started looking for the task, so even if it has run before it is likely unlogged.

Although I have found an option to filter audits in Event Viewer, I do not know about anything similar on Task Scheduler.

I am reletively new to cybersecutiry so I apologize if this is an obvious question.

Is it possible to filter tasks by action in Task Scheduler?

If not, why is it not possible and is there any external code or program I could use to narrow down my search?

Comment: Without specifics, it's hard to help. *Which* service? Scheduled Tasks can be listed by executable, if you have some idea of the executable name or location. Take a look at Nirsoft's TaskSchedulerView  for more search capability. https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/task_scheduler_view.html

Answer (score 2):

If you looking for something to list scheduled tasks, does the following PowerShell help you:

```
Get-ScheduledTask | ForEach-Object {[pscustomobject]@{
  Name = $_.TaskName;
  Path = $_.TaskPath;
  LastResult = $(($_ | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo).LastTaskResult);
  NextRun = $(($_ | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo).NextRunTime);
  Status = $_.State;
  Command = $_.Actions.execute;
  Arguments = $_.Actions.Arguments }
} | Out-GridView
```

You should be able to paste that into either a PowerShell or PowerShell ISE windows running as Administrator and it will provide a GridView of the data that can be filtered using the GridView control.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for lending a hand!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is a scheduled task that's doing this? Your mention of cybersecurity in this context leads me to believe the service is being disabled maliciously.

[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) is a very useful utility which displays many load points in Windows, including scheduled tasks.

- Use the filter field to help narrow down your search.
- Use **Options** > **Scan Options** and check **Check VirusTotal.com** to check entries against VirusTotal (though, a simple script/executable which
  disables a service may not show up).
- Remove the disk and attach it to another machine (or boot to another Windows OS on the same machine) and choose **File** > **Analyze Offline System**. This can reveal items whose presence may be hidden if a rootkit is present.